# Поиск подтсроки HTML в строке c помощью JQuery

Tags: jquery

Я получаю с помощью ajax от сервера кусок html  кода. Для примеру возьмем следующий :

```
<div id='1'>string1</div>
<div id='2'>string2</div>
<div id='3'>string3</div>
```

Затем это вставляется в нужное место с помощью `$('selector').html()` но перед вставкой мне нужно удалить, скажем `div` с `id='2'`. Как это сделать именно перед вставкой кода в DOM? Про regex знаю, но хотелось бы использовать jquery  и селектор CSS.

Comment: сделать из ответа jQuery объект, удалить из него что надо, и потом оставшееся вставить с помощью append

Comment: @Grundy, как преобразовать ответ в объект jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделать из ответа jQuery объект, удалить из него что надо, и потом оставшееся вставить с помощью [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
var html = `<div id='1'>string1</div>
<div id='2'>string2</div>
<div id='3'>string3</div>`

var jQueryObj = $(html);

//filter
var t = jQueryObj.filter((_,el)=> el.id != 2);
$('.selector').append(t);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selector"></div>
```

Comment: но CSS selector все равно не применить при использовании функции filter()?

Comment: @koks_rs, при фильтре нет, но можно обернуть это в контейнер, тогда будет доступна функция find в которой можно использовать селектор.